# Function inside object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Well, i don't know if the `return` in the `transform` function can work, but, someone know if there is a way where i can get something similar to this? Put a function inside an object...

```
var t = $(this).scrollTop();
var h = $(window).height();

function transform(val){
    return "-webkit-transform": "translateY(" + val + "%)",
    "-ms-transform": "translateY(" + val + "%)",
    "transform": "translateY(" + val + "%)";
}

$("#header").css({
    opacity: 50 * (t/h),
    tranform(50 * (t/h))
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a CSS extension language (like LESS or SCSS) to handle variables, then simply process and use some simple stylesheet.

If you want to stick with JS, I would suggest returning a hash from `transform` and extending that later, like:

```
function transform(val) {
  return {
    "-webkit-transform": "translateY(" + val + "%)",
    "-ms-transform": "translateY(" + val + "%)",
    "transform": "translateY(" + val + "%)"
  }
}

function transformWithOpacity(val) {
  var base = transform(val);
  base["opacity"] = val;
  return base;
}

var num = 50 * (t/h);
$("#header").css(transformWithOpacity(num));
```

Comment: Hashes are called "objects" in Javascript.

Comment: @Barmar Objects are a specific type of construct in the ES spec, but "hash" is colloquially used to indicate an object with no constructor, custom prototype chain, and typically no methods (a simple hash of values rather than a constructed instance).

Comment: I haven't noticed that usage convention.

Comment: I'm with Barmar on this. The colloquial use of "hash" just invites confusion. It is called an object in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JQuery extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) function for this

```
$("#header").css($.extend({
    opacity: 50 * (t/h)
  },
  tranform(50 * (t/h))
));
```